# Macbook pro 13 2015 или Macbook pro 13 2016 для xcode и Android studio

Tags: ios, xcode, android-studio, macos, mac

Возникла потребность о замене компа на продукцию от Apple (не хочеться работать в xcode на виртуальной машине)

Выбор стоит перед такими ноутами: MacBook Pro 13 Retina 2015 или MacBook Pro 13 2016
Плюсы первой модели: наличие HDMI, и большего количества портов чем в версии 2016 года (размер экрана мало важен, т.к. подключается монитор)

Суть вопроса: какой из ноутбуков выбрать в конце 2017 года, насколько морально устарела модель 15 года? Есть ли смысл её брать, или всё же лучше взять модель 16 года?

Работать буду в Android Studio и Xcode

Comment: можно такие вопросы вроде на toster.ru задавать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не по тематике данного сайта.

Ну а по вопросу - мало требований. Если не важна цена - берите сразу 2017 года.

Если хотите дешево, но мощно - найдите 15" 2012 года (не retina) с i7 2.7 Ггц и если не в максимальной комплектации - добавьте ОЗУ, 1 или 2 SSD и хватит его еще надолго.

Answer (score 1):

Различия для такой работы по сути только в процессоре и в работе жёсткого диска (не знаю как для XCode, но для Android Studio скорость чтения и записи имеет очень большое значение), сравните данные показатели. В версии 2016 года конечно всё получше, но если ещё есть вопрос цены, то версия 2015 года наверное подойдёт больше, также если размер экрана не важен, то наверное стоит обратить внимание на 15 дюймовый с Intel Core i7.